# Laravel 5.3 : Larevel Echo - Can't retrieve the notification broadcast through Pusher

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I can't seem to retrieve the notification broadcast through Pusher

Pusher configuration **(config/broadcasting.php)**:

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap1',
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
    ],
```

---

How I send* the notification(tested both method) : **(SomeController.php)**

```
// User::find(7)->notify(new OrderProcess());
Notification::send(User::find(7), new OrderProcess());
```

---

**[The problem]** How I retrieve the notification: **(app.js)** and yes, already tried on **bootstrap.js**

```
    import Echo from "laravel-echo"

    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: 'some_key',
        cluster: 'ap1'
    });

    var test = window.Echo.private('App.User.7')
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type); // this never come up
    });
```

Comment: Did you compile `app.js` by `gulp`?